# MySQL Great Circle intersection (do two roads cross?)

Tags: mysql, great-circle, opengis

MySQL OpenGIS CROSSES doesn't seem to work for me:

```
SET @ls = 'LineString(1 1, 2 2, 3 3)';
SET @xx = 'LineString(0 2, 10 2)';

# SELECT AsText(EndPoint(GeomFromText(@ls)));
select crosses(GeomFromText(@ls), GeomFromText(@xx))
```

returns 0 - expected 1

How would I rewrite this as a MySQL function?

Bonus points for using lat, lon and spherical projection (and maybe the Great Circle.)

PS I can't create tags and I have lost my old login: Useful tags would be: MySQL OpenGIS CROSSES greatcircle lat lon - :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in the end I just implemented this: http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/lineline2d/

Answer (score 1):

Just use **INTERSECTS(line1,line2)**

```
SET @ls = 'LineString(1 0,1 2)';
SET @xx = 'LineString(0 1, 2 1)';
select INTERSECTS(GeomFromText(@ls), GeomFromText(@xx));
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that function :( duh! I'm going to leave my question as unanswered as I'd like to see if anyone has an INTERSECTS that works on a sphere.

Comment: SET @aa = 'LineString(0 3,  5 10)';
SET @bb = 'LineString(0 0, 10 10)';
select INTERSECTS(GeomFromText(@aa), GeomFromText(@bb)) AS i;
returns 1 - these lines don't intersect? Or am I being thick?

Comment: OK, INTERSECTS is flawed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610762/mysql-geometry-intersection-produces-non-intersecting-results