# MySQL LineString intersections with Linestring or Polygon

Tags: php, mysql, polygon, spatial

I have a problem with mySQL spatial functions. My target is to find out if a LINESTRING object is passing through a POLYGON object or not. To determine that I've tried to experiment with two LINESTRING objects to determine if they cross or not.

```
SET @ls='LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 3 3)'; -- original linestring
SET @lp='LINESTRING (0 1, 1 2, 2 3, 3 4)'; -- parallel linestring
SET @lx='LINESTRING (0 3, 1 2, 2 1, 3 0)'; -- crossed linestring
```

i've tried several functions to reach my goal:

```
SELECT crosses(GeomFromText(@ls), GeomFromText(@lx)); -- crossing linestrings
returns 0;

SELECT intersects(GeomFromText(@ls), GeomFromText(@lp)); -- parallel linestrings
returns 1;

SELECT overlaps(GeomFromText(@ls), GeomFromText(@lp)); -- parallel linestrings
returns 1;
```

I understand that it is the question of boundary comparison or sth but is there a way (or a function, or a simple solution) how to reach my goal? Other possibility would be to check if a POINT in LINESTRING is within a POLYGON but I was wondering if there's another way to do this?

solution provided in [MySQL Great Circle intersection (do two roads cross?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604430/mysql-great-circle-intersection-do-two-roads-cross) doesn't help me unfortunately..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MySQL documentation for **['Functions That Test Spatial Relationships Between Geometries'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html)** in 5.6.1:

> MySQL originally implemented these functions such that they used object bounding rectangles and returned the same result as the corresponding MBR-based functions. As of MySQL 5.6.1, corresponding versions are available that use precise object shapes. These versions are named with an ST_ prefix. For example, Contains() uses object bounding rectangles, whereas ST_Contains() uses object shapes.
>
> As of MySQL 5.6.1, there are also ST_ aliases for existing spatial functions that were already exact. For example, ST_IsEmpty() is an alias for IsEmpty()

Your `intersects` function, for example, returns true because the minimum bounding rectangle (MBR) of the two shapes *do* intersect. If you use `ST_Intersects` instead (provided you have MySQL 5.6.1 or higher) then it will return false as intended. These functions can be used with points, lines and polygons - so should solve your 'line intersecting polygon' query also ( `ST_Crosses` also exists if required).

Comment: Yes, fortunately for me the newer versions support the ST_ prefix. I fixed it already a while back but forgot about the thread here. :) Thanks for your response.