# how make mysql query for that case

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

I make my real case more simple.

The case:

There are multiple curves they are passed in points and each of them have final 1 point.The final point represented in database as biggest point_order value of the curve.

Should be find curves that pass in specific  point and have same final point (same point_id)

The case(tables):

point table:

```
point_id|x|y
```

**Edit:**

curve_points table example - find all curves that have same point_id=80 and same final point:

```
id|curve_id|point_id|point_order
  |119     |6       |12
  |119     |80      |9
  |119     |1000    |1
  |76      |80      |7
  |76      |6       |9
  |76      |2       |2
  |90      |80      |7
  |90      |6       |9
  |90      |99      |15
```

Output result should be:

```
  |curve_id|
  |119     | 
  |76      |
```

Because the curves 119,76 have same final point=6 and have same  point 80.
Curve 90 not because the point 6 not his final point

psedocode function - **need to add code for choose same final point**:

```
function findCurvesForSamePointAndSameFinalPoint(pointID){
    query="SELECT curve_id FROM curve INNER JOIN point GROUP BY curve_id HAVING point_id="+pointID+";";
    return getDATABASEResult(query);  
}
```

Edit2:
online sql with some data to test:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59e9f/1 (the existed query there not works)

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that final point and pass point are the same or you need  curves which their final points are the same?

Comment: Please further elaborate your question. It is still unclear

Comment: Thanks for comments I edit the question - its contain example of input and output.

Answer (score 1):

If I've got it right. It is something like this:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34268/9)

```
select distinct c1.curve_id,(select point_id from curve t1
       where t1.curve_id=c1.curve_id 
       order by point_order desc 
       limit 1)
TheLastPoint

from curve c1
join curve c2 on
(select point_id from curve t1
       where t1.curve_id=c1.curve_id 
       order by point_order desc 
       limit 1)
=
(select point_id from curve t2 
       where t2.curve_id=c2.curve_id 
       order by point_order desc 
       limit 1)
And c1.curve_id<>c2.curve_id

where c1.curve_id in (select curve_id from curve where point_id=80)
      and 
      c2.curve_id in (select curve_id from curve where point_id=80)
order by TheLastPoint,c1.curve_id
```

Comment: Query now is fixed according with your data.

Comment: Why not? It selects all pairs according your conditions. In your example there are two groups of curves that contain point - 80 and have the same final point . 76,119 have final point 6 and the second group 70,90,92 have final point 99

Answer (score 0):

First thing I want to ask, how Curve table is creating relation with point table? There must be REDUNDANT Curve_ids to map them with Point table.

If it is possible to change your Database Structure, you can use MySQL [Geometry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-geometry.html), which has built in classes like [Point](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-point.html) and [Curve](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-curve.html). You can check if two curves [crosses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html) and many more using built in functionality.

[I found this one related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604430/mysql-great-circle-intersection-do-two-roads-cross)

Comment: thanks, i fix the mistake - curve_points table and not curve only table

Comment: Its existed database can't change schema